# How do I prevent two different accounts from signing in to a website from different tabs of the same browser in php like facebook

Tags: php, session

I trying to develop a website that makes good use of sessions but am having this problem of the session of the second user overriding the session of the first user if I sign in two different accounts on different tabs of the same browser.It is causing my scripts to misbehave. I noticed on facebook that two different accounts can't sign in different tabs of one browser.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: so user cannot keep logged in?

Comment: if you're logged in on tab A and you open up tab B and try to hit the same site that has a running session, won't your browser exchange info with your server that identifies it as being the same browser (+ cookies) and log you into the site automatically since a session already exists?

Comment: I would do some research on sessions before posting here. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions.

Comment: yea @FastSnail I dont really know whether it is bad practice cause I used sessions to carry a lot of user details through my script,  two users using the same browser can cause problems sometimes, I dont know whether there is any code that can prevent two users from using one browser at the same time.

Comment: Why are you allowing a user to log in if they are already logged in? Session is shared between tabs, so you can tell if the visitor is already logged in.